# How can I print a specific range of lines from a file in linux?

Tags: linux, unix

If I have a file with 100,000 lines, how can I print lines in a specified range, such as lines 15010 to 15020?

Comment: what did you try ? you want to do in linux shell script ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried something like "head -15010 filename | tail 10", but it seems cost too much. I'm wondering whether there's another option.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '15010,15020p' input.txt
```

#### `awk`:

```
$ awk '15010<=NR && NR <=15020' input.txt
```

#### `head/tail`:

```
$ head -n 15020 input.txt | tail -n $((15020-15010+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `head` and `tail`:

```
head -15020 f.txt | tail -11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of head and tail. Something like:

```
head  -15010 filename | tail -11
```